# On a property of a holomorphic function on a unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorhic function on the open unit disk $D$. Suppose that there is an $r\in[0,1)$ such that restriction of $f$ to the annulus
$$U=\left\{z\in C:r<\left|z\right|<1\right\}$$
is one-to-one. Prove that $f$ is one-to-one on $D$.

Firstly, $f$ is one-to-one if and only if derivative of $f(x)$ is not zero. So my aim is to use the boundary property of this function to prove the result. I tried Cauchy integral theorem. But it doesn't seem to work very well. Neither do the maximum and minimum principle.

Comment: *$f$ is one-to-one if and only if derivative of $f(x)$ is not zero*  – that is not true in general as the exponential function shows.